# Implementing graphs in java

Tags: java, gwt

What would you recommend to create a graph using Java language . Should it be self coded or which library set do you suggest for it to be  implemented ?

Comment: Do you mean graph as in edges and vertices, or graph as in data plot?

Comment: Graph theory? or more like Cartesian graphs?

Comment: is this homework? like make your own Node class?

Comment: Ya data plotting graph for an web based application.3D graphs which would plot data.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for graphs as in data plots or pie charts or something like that, check out [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) or [the Google chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

If you're meaning something like graph theory, check out [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/).

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Some other interesting options, and as already mentioned no need to reinvent the wheel :)

- http://jung.sourceforge.net/
- http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html

Answer (score 1):

gFloat also has a nice GWT implementation and is free